# How can I regulate the output voltage in this inverter circuit

Tags: voltage, mosfet, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, inverter

Beginner here ! I just modeled this circuit in proteus 8 I saw it from a youtube video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QaKiXRa-n0&feature=youtu.be) 
I want to make this inverter but I can't understand it well enough
. what are your opinions about the circuit and what do I do to regulate the output voltage ? I want to fix at 220V
help please ! thanks

[image: https://imgur.com/a/FKWEN]

Comment: it doesn't seem practical to regulate that.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. That is a square-wave output, because the MOSFETS are either fully ON or fully OFF. You can try duty-cycle adjustments, but it would no longer be a square wave, and the transformer would consume much current. You can only adjust the transformer center-tap voltage, but results will be non-linear. TR2 has a finite range of operation. This is a hobby project - not much more than that.

Comment: Model it.  What do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Use a buck regulator to control the transformer centre-tap voltage. I've used this method and it works.

Advice: you will probably need snubbers across each half winding of the primary in addition to what you have shown in your schematic. This prevents excessive back emf destroying the MOSFETs. I would also consider an output LC filter to get rid of a lot of the output harmonics that could cause RFI to other equipment locally.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it , will this fix the voltage drop ? after I add a lamp  in the simulation the 220v drops to 86v

Comment: help please ! how to fix the voltage drop

Comment: Technical details of the transformer, lamp, 12 volt power supply, output MOSFETs and your voltage measurement device need to be included into your question. Add links to data sheets.

Comment: perhaps the OP should pay attention to the title of the YT video he references.

Comment: @dmb: indeed!!!

Comment: @naytr: How much current is the lamp pulling?  Chances are you're bringing the FETs or the transformer to their knees with too much current.

Answer (score 0):

> Look up dual push-pull   half-bridge BJT driver to parallel Nch only  single half-bridge MOSFET inverter with centre-tapped DC step up transformer.

Load regulation error V on AC depends on **Vac/Ron * n² * Rload**
for Ron of MOSFETS and  for step turns ratio of n.

Poor load regulation without feedback, PWM comes from  high RdsOn.  This is a primitive design.

Assuming each primary winding to tap produces the peak AC voltage out at load 340Vp/12Vdc=28:1=n  n²~ 800

RdsOn = 0.077 Ohms @ Vgs=10V   , two ideally are 1/2 of this

Assuming 40 mOhm * 800 = 32 Ohm = Zout  thus assuming if 240 W rated then 1A - 240 Ohm rated load means Vout changes due to voltage drop from 32 Ohms or ~12% drop , ***which is poor***, less for 100W rating and worse for 300W load or more.

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic shows a 12V lamp overloading the 220V output of the transformer.